# Admin submit order event

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order

I want to fire my custom ajax request when admin click on submit order button.

What I need to do for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use magento event observer for this. Instade of this button click, you can used this event.

1. sales_order_place_after